# RabbitMQ how to only have one message at a time and don't requeue on failure

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, prefetch

Our system has a bunch of consumers that use rabbit to consume messages for long running tasks. Currently we ack at the end of processing, so that if the consumer crashes, the message gets requeued. What we want is that a consumer only works on one message at a time and does not prefetch so that another consumer can work on the next message, and if a crash occurs we do not requeue, but we'll have our own monitor that will decide whether we need to re-run on a larger EC2 instance or whatever. It looks like we can get CLOSE to this by acking at start of processing with a prefetch of 1, but that is still 1 message in the queue that could have been handled by another consumer. Apparently setting prefetch to 0 makes no sense
according to rabbit devs (I don't understand why), so another option would be to still ack only on completion so that a prefetch doesn't occur, but somehow DON'T requeue on crash.

If we are swimming upstream so to speak then I know we'll have to come up with another plan, but I don't understand why the desire for a consumer to only work on one thing at a time (and not prefetch the next item of work) and to not requeue on crash is so odd

Comment: If your consumers are long running and throughput is of no concern, then you might consider [basic get](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/rabbitmq-basic-consume-vs-rabbitmq-basic-get.html) as an alternative to push-based consume. With get, essentially each consumer controls the rate of processing, albeit with the downside of polling overhead. You are right with setting prefetch to 0 when in consume mode- this is regarded as infinite prefetch and is usually a bad idea even in high throughput scenarios.

Comment: @StuartLC right I don't mean setting prefetch to 0 as in the current implementation, but 0 as in "don't prefetch"

Comment: @StuartLC do you know why we have to always prefetch, like why is this considered weird?

Comment: Consume mode is useful in the common scenario where messages flow fast and consumer nodes need to process a large backlog of messages as fast as possible. Prefetching, batch acting, and even auto acting are important tools to allow consumers to keep up with the work rate. You seem to have a different scenario where message rates are low, process times are large, and round robin load balancing is more important than throughput.

Comment: Acking... autocorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using one of the `RabbitTemplate` `receive()` or `receiveAndConvert` methods instead; that's a better model for this type of workload - fetching records as needed instead of them being pushed into your app.